# process sibling nodes and marked as processed

Tags: xml, xslt

Actually i am facing the problem to parse my XML elements with the following condition;
 -- Total columns are 4 and if the total hspan of element nodes became 4 then it treated as one row. For example element 1,2 as row AND 3,4 as row AND 5 should be treated also as row.

```
<elements cols="4">
<element hspan="1" text= "text1"/>
<element hspan="3" text= "text2"/>
<element hspan="2" text= "text3"/>
<element hspan="2" text= "text4"/>
<element hspan="4" text= "text5"/>
</elements>
```

sometime element comes without hspan, in that case the element should be consider as 1 and proceed further.

```
<elements cols="4">
<element text= "text1"/>
<element hspan="3" text= "text2"/>
<element hspan="2" text= "text3"/>
<element hspan="2" text= "text4"/>
<element hspan="4" text= "text5"/>
</elements>
```

if i make loop in my xslt for taking the next sibling nodes, how can i ignore the already processed element.

Expected result is;

```
<row>
  <cells>
        <label text = text1>
        <label text = text2>
  </cells>
</row>
<row>
 <cells>
       <label text = text3>
       <label text = text4>
 </cells>
</row>
<row>
 <cells>
       <label text = text5>
 </cells>
</row>
```

Note: I am using XSLT 2.0.
I am really very thankful for any help.
regards,
Jaji

Comment: Please post the expected result. -- P.S. Why would  elements 1,2 and 3 be in the same row, when elements 1 and 2 have already a total span of 4?

Comment: And now it's not clear what should happen when you already have 3 and the next one is 2.

Comment: @Michael - actually it's defined in hspan that how many columns that element occupied. some time it is 1 for each element which means that each element occupy only one column. one <elements> have more then 20 elements, that's why i want to do it in dynamic (loop or something else) way. I really appreciate ur help.

Comment: I am afraid you have lost me. I am asking how would you divide 3, 1, 3, 2.

Comment: ahhh ... i got you.. NO it is not possible in my xml. the element comes in way that number of cols does not axeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the count of the relevant `@hspan` attributes so always fit exactly into the number of required cols, you could group the elements like so:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="element" group-starting-with="*[sum(preceding-sibling::element/@hspan) mod $cols = 0]">
```

i.e. Sum the preceding elements, and where the sum is divided by 4 exactly, then this indicates a new row.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="elements">
    <xsl:variable name="cols" select="@cols" />
    <xsl:for-each-group select="element" group-starting-with="*[sum(preceding-sibling::element/@hspan) mod $cols = 0]">
      <row>
        <cells>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
        </cells>
      </row>
    </xsl:for-each-group> 
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="element">
     <label text="{@text}" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This would, of course, fail if the `cols` was set to "4" and the first two elements had `hspan` attributes of 2 and 3, for example.

EDIT: In response to comments, if some `element` elements had no `hspan` attributes, your XSLT would look like this (Thanks Martin Honnen!)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="elements">
    <xsl:variable name="cols" select="@cols" />
    <xsl:for-each-group select="element" group-starting-with="*[sum(preceding-sibling::element/xs:decimal((@hspan,1)[1])) mod $cols = 0]">
      <row>
        <cells>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
        </cells>
      </row>
    </xsl:for-each-group> 
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="element">
     <label text="{@text}" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Superb and thank you very much, your solution has resolved my problem. Only one thing I have missed in my question that some time element comes without "hspan". in that case the element should be consider as hspan = "1". Would you please also suggest any solution to resovle this one. Currently whenever i parse the xml elements which contain element without hspan, like "<element  text= "textX"/>" then the desired results are not obtained.

Comment: Change the code to `<xsl:for-each-group select="element" group-starting-with="*[sum(preceding-sibling::element/((@hspan,1)[1]) mod $cols = 0]">`

Comment: @Martin - thanks but i am getting an error of Unexpected token ']' :(

Comment: I am typing on my smartphone so getting brackets right is hard, try `<xsl:for-each-group select="element" group-starting-with="*[sum(preceding-sibling::element/((@hspan,1)[1])) mod $cols = 0]">`

Comment: now getting no compiler error but whenever i transfer my xml getting following error: Mixed content in path expression "XPTY0018: The last step of a path expression may not contain both nodes and atomic values"

Comment: Wrap the `@hspan` into `xs:decimal(@hspan)` and make sure the stylesheet defines the schema namespace.

Comment: Martin -  hurraaa It is working :) Thank you very much for your kind help. @Tim - also thanks for your great help :)

Comment: Thanks Martin Honnen. I've added your amendment to my answer.